# making a trigger

Tags: mysql

Here is a code and i am getting the following error

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4

the trigger is as follows

```
CREATE TRIGGER updtrigger BEFORE UPDATE ON login
FOR EACH ROW
IF NEW.first >100 THEN 
SET PASSWORD = furqan;
END IF;
END
```

Comment: Is the trigger absolutely necessary?  I've been bitten in the past and can find a different solution most of the time.  Again, are you sure a trigger is needed?

Comment: I guess he's just trigger happy! :)

Answer (score 3):

furqan is a string, and it should be in quotes

```
CREATE TRIGGER updtrigger BEFORE UPDATE ON login
FOR EACH ROW
IF NEW.first >100 THEN 
SET PASSWORD = 'furqan';
END IF;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP TRIGGER /*!50032 IF EXISTS */ `updtrigger`$$

CREATE
    /*!50017 DEFINER = 'root'@'localhost' */
    TRIGGER `updtrigger` AFTER INSERT ON `login` 
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF new.first >100 THEN 
        SET new.password = 'furqan';
    END IF;
END;
$$

DELIMITER ;
```